# How to initialize Object[] in java dynamically?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I created object in global as.

```
public Object[] columns2;
```

I am performing some operation in code as:

```
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Gtest+"");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 for(int n=0;n<NumOfCol;n++)
  {
   columns2[n]=rsmd.getColumnName(n+1);
  }
```

as columns2 should be like

```
  Object[] columns2={"FirstName","LastName","Age"};
```

But it is giving nullpointerexception in for loop.

What changes should be done?

Answer (score 5):

You must initiate `columns2` first before push there data.

```
columns2 = new Object[NumOfCol];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Gtest+"");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();
columns2 = new Object[NumOfCol];
for(int n=0;n<NumOfCol;n++)
{
  columns2[n]=rsmd.getColumnName(n+1);
}
```

Comment: @maxim and all 
thanxxxxxxxxxxx alooooooooot
wohaaaa my program is working.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized columns2. You could change your code as follows:

```
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Gtest+"");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 NumOfCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();
 columns2 = new Object[NumOfCol];
 for(int n=0;n<NumOfCol;n++)
 {
   columns2[n]=rsmd.getColumnName(n+1);
 }
```

This should make your code work. Although i would look into other Data Structures like an Arraylist if things like performance are important to you.